# ConcurrentModificationException and Stream API

Tags: java, spring-boot

Why I am getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException even when I am using removeIf?What change is required in my code ?

```
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        namesList.add("AA");
        namesList.add("BB");
        namesList.add("CC");
List<String> createList =null;
                namesList.stream()
            .map(m->  { namesList.removeIf( m1 -> m1=="AA" ) ; return m;   }   )
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You can replace it with `namesList.remove("AA")`

Comment: Note that you're comparing strings with `==`. **Never do that.** Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Exception because you are deleting item while iterating them. ArrayList is thread unsafe. so Use  `Collections.synchronizedCollection(namesList);`

Answer (score 3):

This is happening as your are modifying the *source* of the *stream* which is a non-concurrent `ArrayList`. The `ArrayListSpliterator` does not have the **CONCURRENT**  or **IMMUTABLE** characteristic and it does not support removal during iteration. It is not due to usage of the `Collection.removeIf` method.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#IMMUTABLE):

> A Spliterator that does not report IMMUTABLE or CONCURRENT is expected
>   to have a documented policy (for example throwing
>   ConcurrentModificationException concerning structural interference
>   detected during traversal.

For this to work you need to have `List` implementation which supports concurrent removal during iteration like a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, whose `Spliterator` has the **IMMUTABLE** characteristic.

Anyway, you are not using the `map` operation correctly if you want to conditionally ***filter*** items from the `List` you should use `Stream.filter` instead also consider using `equals` while comparing `String` objects:

```
namesList.stream()
         .filter(m1 -> !"AA".equals(m1))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @AndyTurner I missed to see the `.collect` there! it is totally redundant. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to remove the value `"AA"` from your list, here are your options:

- `namseList.removeIf(s -> s.equals("AA"))` - no need to deal with `Stream`s.
- `namesList.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("AA")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Some points:

- You are calling `.collect()` on a `Stream` followed by `forEach()`. This can be simplified to simply call `forEach()` on the `Stream` object.
- You are comparing `String`s using `==`. This can do what you intend (i.e. compare their values, because of String interning), but it is good practice to compare *values* using `.equals()`.

  - the call: `.map(m -> {namesList.removeIf(...); return m})` is equivalent to `.map(m -> m)` (i.e. it does not do anything).

You probably want to use something like:
    List namesList = ...
    namesList.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("AA")).forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 0):

[ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>   For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it.

***This exception occurs because you are modifying the stream source.***

```
namesList.stream().map(m->  { namesList.removeIf( m1 -> m1=="AA" ) ; return m;   }   )
```

you can simply call below code:

```
namesList.removeIf( m1 -> m1=="AA" )
```

Or As [@Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) suggested:

```
nameList.removeAll(Collections.singleton("AA"));
```

Comment: "you can simply call below code:" `nameList.remove("AA");` would be simpler again.

Comment: @AndyTurner it only removes  the first occurrence of the specified element from this list. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Then `nameList.removeAll(Collections.singleton("AA"));`.

Comment: I think removeAll take collection rather then object to remove https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-

Comment: It does. `Collections.singleton` is a `Collection` (a `Set`, more specifically).

Comment: ohh replayed already when only singleton was written :P, Yeah  this will work too. Thanks